# Using Javascript to alter every url on page

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if there is a name for what I want to do, but I would like to use javascript to alter every url on a webpage on my website.  So if someone posts a url such as:

> visit http://www.blah.com

when viewing this page, I want javascript to change it to:

> visit http://www.mysite.com/count.php?out=http://www.blah.com

I know about the two urls in one I will handle that part, I just used this as an example of placing the same text in front of every url in the page.  Kinda like how thewaybackmachine does it.  Thanks.

Comment: Javascript can do this. What exactly is your question?

Comment: The url you gave is an PHP GET url. Why do you want to use javascript for this?

Comment: Darn sorry you are right, I just found out that php works.  I am searching for a PHP way to do this now.

Comment: If you have something like page.php?id=test, you can access the sent information with $_GET['id'] inside your PHP code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$("a").attr('href', "http://test.com?blah=" + $(this).attr('href'));
```

This code searches for all `a` tags on the page, and replaces the contents of the `href` attribute with `http://test.com?blah=` followed by the original contents of the `href` attribute.

To try it out, You can copy it, hit 'f12', paste it into the console, hit enter, and see it's effects on this page right here! (also breaking all your links...)

Comment: OP didn't tag it jquery

Comment: I'd recommend that if you're not proficient in JavaScript, you get jQuery and use it and learn it.

Comment: @DeanRather Could not agree with you more. And, wow, I literally just typed the same thing. Oh well.

Comment: @DeanRather I would recommend forget about jQuery before you learn how to do that without it.

Comment: Dean, you are right for copy - pasters.
@dfsq, your statement is valid for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, without the need for JQuery. (loading and parsing a pretty big library in order to just do one simple thing may be a bit much..)

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a')).map(function(a){ a.href = 'http://somesite.com/count.php?' + a.href })
```